# Damage indicator move in an arc

Tags: movement, gui

I'm trying to imitate the damage indicator in Ragnarok online (moving in an arc): sample [here](https://youtu.be/cPFfF0GJL2U).
But I can only do [this](https://youtu.be/XIT3TG66cys)

I have this code below. I'm not sure how to make it go faster. If I do `pos.y += 2 * yOffset;`, it will just go higher.

```
public void update(float delta) {
    if(xOffset < Math.PI) {
        xOffset += delta;
        pos.x += xOffset;
    }
    if(xOffset >= Math.PI) {
        xOffset = Math.PI;
    }
    yOffset = (float)(3 * -Math.sin(2*xOffset));
    if(xOffset < Math.PI) {
        pos.y += yOffset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want "gravity physics" instead of a sine wave. So you'll need to give your damage indicator a velocity and an acceleration. The acceleration is what creates the nice curved parabola path for your object.

```
public void update(float delta)
{
    speed += <your_gravity_strength>;

    pos.x += delta;
    pos.y += speed;
}
```

Now, when you create your damage indicator, set `speed` to something negative, so that the text moves up for a while first. The  gravity number will then start to slow the movement up until the text starts actually moving down. You probably don't want to make either value too large (the initial speed nor the gravity), but try out some values and see what you like.